# How to enable ocsp stapling in existing NodeJS backend?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, ocsp

I am totally new to NodeJS and today I had to update a ssl certificate in an existing NodeJS backend. I have never done anything with node and the guy that has written the application does not work for the company anymore...

So far so good... updating the certificates was no problem, I only had to change the pathes. After restarting the node backend and checking the application I got an error in my browser because of the required ocsp stapling.

I have already enabled ocsp in apache and nginx but I have no idea what to do with node.

I already installed ocsp node module via npm.

Here is the app.js code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var config = require('./config.js');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// ssl options
if (config.https) {
    var options = {
        ca: fs.readFileSync(config.sslCa),
        key: fs.readFileSync(config.sslKey),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(config.sslCert)
    };
}

var app = express();
var server;
if (config.https) {
    server = https.createServer(options, app);
} else {
    server = http.Server(app);
}

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
require('./socketEvents')(io);
var rest = require('./restRoutes')(io);
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
var verifyToken = require('./verifyToken');
var fileManagement = require('./fileManagement')(io);
var authorization = require('./authorization');
var restFiles = require('./restFiles')(io);

// serve static files
app.use('/bundles', express.static(config.iboxWebDir + '/bundles'));

var multer = require('multer');

// path for diskStorage
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './files');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});

// multer function to store the file
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

// CORS OPTIONS
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true, maxAge: 600}));
app.use(morgan('dev')); // use morgan to log requests to the console

app.use('/icons', express.static(__dirname + '/../' + 'icons'));

// icon files
app.use('/restfiles', restFiles);

// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // parse json-request
app.post('/file/upload', verifyToken, upload.fields([{name: 'roomId'}, {name: 'threadId'}, {name: 'files'}]), fileManagement.postFile);

// configure body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse json-request
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // parse urlencoded from requests

app.get('/file/get', verifyToken, fileManagement.getFile);
app.post('/file/get', verifyToken, fileManagement.getFile);
app.post('/file/remove', verifyToken, authorization.canRemoveFile, fileManagement.removeFile);

// add router for rest api
app.use('/rest', rest);

module.exports = server;
```

Hopefully there is someone who can give me some help.

Thanks a lot!

Philip

Comment: I found some documentation for nodeJs and ocsp. But unfortunately I can't get it together... (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ocsp)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
...
var ocsp = require('ocsp')
...
var app = express();
var server;
if (config.https) {
    var ocspCache = new ocsp.Cache()
    server = https.createServer(options, app);

    server.on('OCSPRequest', function(cert, issuer, callback) {
        ocsp.getOCSPURI(cert, function(err, uri) {
            if (err) return callback(error);
            var req = ocsp.request.generate(cert, issuer);
            var options = {
                url: uri,
                ocsp: req.data
            };
            ocspCache.request(req.id, options, callback);
        });
    });

    // eventually you can omit this
    var sslSessionCache = {};
    server.on('newSession', function(sessionId, sessionData, callback) {
        sslSessionCache[sessionId] = sessionData;
        callback();
    });
    server.on('resumeSession', function (sessionId, callback) {
        callback(null, sslSessionCache[sessionId]);
    });
} else {
    server = http.Server(app);
}
...
```

I got the modification from here

> https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8660

Best regards

Dietrich

Comment: I forgot to mention that you also have to install the ocsp module with "npm install ocsp".